# Is a Mac's login password the weakest link, and if so, how complex does it need to be?

Tags: macos, security, passwords

Let's assume you have FileVault2 enabled, and use Keychain to store passwords for everything else. Your AppleID is protected with two factor auth, and you've disabled AppleID-based mac recovery.

It seems to me that a Mac's login password are the key to the kingdom, since it unlocks the FileVault decryption keys and unlocks the Keychain.

As such how complex does a Mac login password need to be? On my iPhone I can get away a 6 digit pin, but that's because I know that after a certain number of failed attempts, the iPhone will lock out any further attempts, and even erase the phone if I enable that feature. You cannot brute force you way into an iPhone (Am I wrong?)  What does a Mac have to prevent a brute force login password attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no auto-lockout on failed password attempts on Mac.

Bear in mind any brute force attack is limited by how fast someone can type. It's not like they can hit it with 2000 tries a second.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739874/how-many-possible-combinations-in-8-character-password for number of possible combinations.

See also https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: Can't someone use the USB port to spoof a keyboard and the programmatically rifle through lots of combinations?

Comment: It's not something I'd really worry about unless you think you deserve the attention of an angry government agency. By that time, I'm sure you'd also have a lot more to worry about.

Comment: well i had no idea the scale of the difficulty. e.g. all my bank accounts are accessible though my keychain, is it easy enough to make it worthwhile for a thief or not. I mean people have hacked the credit card system, there are USB sticks that spoof a keyboard to type in code and run it, etc. OTOH i get it; hence the xkcd addition.